# Maven Cobertura + Maven War Plugins

Tags: maven, cobertura, maven-war-plugin

I'm with a trouble with these plugins, got the following exception:

```
[INFO] Error configuring: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin. Reason: ERROR: Cannot override read-only parameter: classesDirectory in goal: war:exploded
```

I also found [this issue on JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOBERTURA-86), thats unresolved.

Anyway, I'll like too much to see it working. Anyone know another plugin to do this, or a workaround to made it work?

Thank in advance.

[EDIT]

I added the Cobertura plugin in my parent pom project, like this:

```xml
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        [...]
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And them when I run "mvn site", I got the exception as I said before.

About the JIRA issue, I accidentaly paste the wrong link, sorry. Its updated now.

BTW: I've tried the workaround describe in this issue, without success.

Comment: If you like to get it resolved there are two possible ways. First vote for the problem in JIRA or just start a patch..and mail it to the mailing list or better attach it to the jira.

Comment: The issue is for emma plugin, the exception is for war plugin and the subject line refers to cobertura.  What exactly are you trying to do and when do you get the problem?  Relevant pom snippet will help.

Comment: Does your regular build (e.g. `mvn package`) work without issues, and therefore the issue is isolated just to `mvn site:site`? If so, can you post a little more context prior to the error you're pointing at? Have you verified you don't have this problem if you remove the Cobertura plugin?

Comment: Got solution for this? Recently i had same issue, but solved after i re-orderd the plugins

Comment: @RaghunandanKrishnamurthy nope..